# Using mediaquery in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries, tooltip

I got a tooltip which falls out of screen on mobile. So I want to change the options of the tooltip depending on what device the tooltip is opened. Open from the side on desktop and open from the top on mobile.

How can I do that in javascript?

My code with options:

```
$scope.initToolTip = function(item) {
      $timeout(function() {
        var tooltip = $('.tooltip'+item.id).tooltipster({
            contentCloning: true,
            interactive: true,
            side:'left',
            delay:50,
            animationDuration:300
        });
      },100);
    };
```

Devices with a max width of 760px should have side:top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) for this. It works like this (example from linked Mozilla Developer Network article):

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
  /* the viewport is at least 400 pixels wide */
} else {
  /* the viewport is less than 400 pixels wide */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is using `screen.width`.

```
$scope.initToolTip = function(item) {
      $timeout(function() {
        var tooltip = $('.tooltip'+item.id).tooltipster({
            contentCloning: true,
            interactive: true,
            // if screen width is 760 or bigger set to left else set top
            side: screen.width >= 760 ? 'left' : 'top',

            delay:50,
            animationDuration:300
        });
      },100);
    };
```

Comment: also $(window).width()

Comment: Results of $(window).width() can differ from the ones of media queries: https://www.fourfront.us/blog/jquery-window-width-and-media-queries. This might be important when using both.